# If I selected true value assign to other select option via jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, jquery-select2

I am sorry if subject is confused.

I have two select on my site. It uses [select2](https://select2.github.io/) plugin.

First select :

```
<select name="" id="">
    <option value="one"></option>
    <option value="two"></option>
    <option value="three"></option>
    <option value="four"></option>
    <option value="five"></option>
</select>
```

And other one :

```
<select name="" id="">
    <option value="other_one"></option>
    <option value="other_two"></option>
    <option value="other_three"></option>
    <option value="other_four"></option>
    <option value="other_five"></option>
</select>
```

There is a logic of them. If checked value `one` the value must be `other_one`in other select (and other options should be disabled). Likewise, the other select options will work this case.

I research on https://select2.github.io/options.html#adapters and Stackoverflow, yes I can add trigger to selects and for example print html or text but I need different one.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add on change event and change the value of second select `#select2` depending on selected one from first select `#select1`.

Hope this helps.

```js
$("#select1, #select2").select2(); 

$("#select1").on('change',function()
{
    $('#select2 option').removeAttr('disabled');

    var selected_1_value = $(this).val();

    $("#select2").val('other_'+selected_1_value).change();
    $("#select2 option:not(:selected)").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.5.2/select2.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.5.2/select2.min.js"></script>

<select name="" id="select1">
    <option value="one">1</option>
    <option value="two">2</option>
    <option value="three">3</option>
    <option value="four">4</option>
    <option value="five">5</option>
</select>
<select name="" id="select2">
    <option value="other_one">other 1</option>
    <option value="other_two">other 2</option>
    <option value="other_three">other 3</option>
    <option value="other_four">other 4</option>
    <option value="other_five">other 5</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you for solution. I changed a litte bit for my structure but doesn't work if-else condition. Please can you check that? http://pastebin.com/WcGH4ffT

Comment: You're welcome, check if there's any error msg in console, if you can make a fiddle for your code so i can check with you.

Answer (score 1):

```
<select name="" id="select1">
<option value="one">one</option>
<option value="two">two</option>
<option value="three">three</option>
<option value="four">four</option>
<option value="five">five</option>
```

```
<select name="" id="select2">
    <option value="other_one">other_one</option>
    <option value="other_two">other_two</option>
    <option value="other_three">other_three</option>
    <option value="other_four">other_four</option>
    <option value="other_five">other_five</option>
</select>

$('select').select2();

$("#select1").change(function()
{   
    $('#select2 option').prop("disabled",false); // remove disabled on all options - basically do a reset
    $('#select2 option:selected').prop("disabled",true); // disable the current selected option
   $('#select2').select2().select2('val', "other_" + $(this).val()); // set the value of #select2 by concatenating the value from #select1
    $('#select2 option:not(:selected)').prop("disabled",true); // disable all other non-selected options
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/o5y9959b/10/